# Data not return from Google Photo Intent android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have been trying to load an image from Google Photos App into my application. When I choose an image in Google Photos, my application crashes, but if I select the image from the Gallery App, it works. Please what am I missing out? Find my code below.

```
itemImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pickImage();
        }

    });


public void pickImage() {
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    galleryIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    galleryIntent.putExtra("outputX", 100);
    galleryIntent.putExtra("outputY", 100);
    galleryIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
    galleryIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        try {

            //Uri uri = data.getData();

            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            itemImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            String encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

            byte[] bytarray = Base64.decode(encodedImageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            bmimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytarray, 0,
                    bytarray.length);

        } catch (Exception e){}

    }

}
```

I have tweaked the code a little bit. Now I can import all images on the Gallery and Photos app except for camera images. See my new code below:

```
public void pickImage() {
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        try {

            //Uri uri = data.getData();

            final Uri uri = data.getData();
            final InputStream imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            itemImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            String encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

            byte[] bytarray = Base64.decode(encodedImageString, Base64.DEFAULT);

            /*bmimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytarray, 0,
                    bytarray.length);*/


        } catch (Exception e){}



    }


}
```

Comment: `ACTION_PICK` does not have extras for cropping, and `ACTION_PICK` should never return a `Bitmap` as the `"data"` extra.

Comment: @CommonsWare,please what is the correct code....

Comment: `ACTION_PICK` returns a `Uri` via `getData()` on the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()`. To show that image in an `ImageView`, pass the `Uri` to your favorite image-loading library (e.g., Picasso). You will not have sufficient heap space to convert most images into a base64 string.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. I have tweaked the code now according to your advice. I can import all images except camera images. Any ideas on why? My code is shown above.

Comment: "Any ideas on why?" -- no, because you are catching an exception and not logging it. My guess is that you are getting an `OutOfMemoryException`, because, as I noted, you will not have sufficient heap space to convert most images into a base64 string.